# What should I use for the while loop?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, netbeans, while-loop

This is my coding so far - instructor asked me to create a program that creates triangles and specifies them.Here are the actual instructions for clarity:

*Write a program that creates sets of random triangle sides using integer values between 3 and 13. The user will specify how many triangles they would like created by entering an integer value between 1 and 10 (you may assume that they will enter an integer in this range).

For each triangle the user has requested, your program should:

1. Generate a set of 3 random integers between 3 and 13.
2. Display the 3 numbers
3. Decide if the numbers represent the sides of a valid triangle. (For example, 5, 5, and 13 do NOT create a triangle).
   --- If the numbers do not represent a valid triangle, display an appropriate error message.
   --- If the numbers are valid, the program should determine, and display, the
   a) side classification of the triangle – equilateral, isosceles, or scalene, and
   b) the angle classification of the triangle – right, acute, or obtuse*

   // I need to figure out what to use in the while loop. I haven't written all of the coding yet, but there is an empty while loop (which im trying to use to calculate the userInput x apple and orange (yes I did use fruits as ints)

   // Writing all coding here:

   ```
   // Declaring maximum and minimum values for user input:
   int maxValue = 13;
   int minValue = 3;

   userInteger = (int) (maxValue * Math.random()) + minValue;
   userInteger2 = (int) (maxValue * Math.random()) + minValue;
   userInteger3 = (int) (maxValue * Math.random()) + minValue;

   String banana = (userInput.getText());
   {
       while()
           outcomeLabel.setText("Your numbers are: " + userInteger + ", " + userInteger2 + " and " + userInteger3 + "." +
                   "\n" + "The number of triangles requested is" + banana + "so the result is");
   }

   int apple = (userInteger + userInteger2);
   int orange = (userInteger3);
   {
       if (apple == orange)
           outcomeLabel.setText("Your numbers are: " + userInteger + ", " + userInteger2 + " and " + userInteger3 + "." +
                   "\n" + "The number of triangles requested is" + banana + "\n" + "The numbers make a triangle.");
       else
           outcomeLabel.setText("Your numbers are: " + userInteger + ", " + userInteger2 + " and " + userInteger3 + "." +
                   "\n" + "The number of triangles requested is" + banana + "\n" + "The numbers do not make a triangle - try again.");
   }

   {
       if(userInteger == userInteger2 && userInteger == userInteger3)
           outcomeLabel.setText("Your numbers are: " + userInteger + ", " + userInteger2 + " and " + userInteger3 + "." +
                   "\n" + "The number of triangles requested is" + banana + "\n" + "The numbers make a triangle." + "\n" + "This triangle is an equilateral triangle.");
   }
   {
       if (userInteger == userInteger2) {

       }

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: You should use meaningful variables names instead of silly ones. It might be funny for you but when someone tries to read your code and they have no idea why your integers are named by fruits it just wastes their time. Plus, when you go back to read your code months or even weeks from now you'll wish you just used meaningful names anyway. :)

Comment: Your random number generation isn't right...The integers you generate will be between 3 and 15, inclusive

Comment: that's irrelevant, they just help me keep track of them easier, I'm going to change them before i enter the assignment. but thanks for the advice...

Comment: Sorry, nitpicking, but your code appears pretty wonky to me... Seems to me that you place your logic inside initialization blocks, which probably won't have the behavior you intend, especially if this is part of a method...

Comment: @user3580294 - I did notice that when I ran my program, that 15's would come up. why is this happening exactly?

Comment: @user3580294 - it is pretty wonky. it works though. what else should I do?? can you give me any recommendations on how to make it more efficient?

Comment: It's probably your random number generation. `(int) (maxValue * Math.random())` produces an integer between `0` and `maxValue - 1`, inclusive, so it's possible for your random numbers to be anywhere from 3 to 15 in this case.

Comment: Is this code part of a method?

Comment: @user3580294 - okay. i'll try to change that. and this is all the code I've written so far. it's a GUI

Comment: But is the code part of a method in the GUI?

Comment: @user3580294 - sorry im not sure what you mean by method, I have very limited knowledge on java

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how curly braces are used.  If you want `statement1`, `statement2`, etc., to be executed in a loop, say `while(whatever) { statement1; statement2; ... }`.  Same for `if`.  Putting the first curly brace **before** the `while` or `if` has a different meaning and does not work.

Comment: @ajb - I most likely have misunderstood how they're used. thanks. this is helpful.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code into an IDE?

Comment: @user3580294 - not sure - I am writing it in netbeans if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your code, your `while` loop might not be in the right place... Ignoring the `while` loop, your code just generates a single set of three numbers and prints whether they would make a triangle, right? So where would you put the `while` loop to do this single action multiple times? In the middle of the provided code doesn't make too much sense...

A few other things: I don't believe your code to determine whether the generated sides can make a triangle works. What happens if `userInteger = userInteger2 = 5`, and `userInteger3 = 4`? And if you want to generate a number of triangles with the number provided by the user, you need some way to convert the inputted `String` into an integer. For that, checkout the `Integer.parseInt()` method: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Finally, you probably want to check out the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

I don't believe your code would work as expected when you first run it. Blocks of code inside plain braces in your class are called "initialization blocks", and are run at object creation every time your class is instantiated. What you probably want is to place everything into a method, which will allow you to run the code on command as many times as you want.

Comment: thanks for answering. yes, it does generate three numbers and print whether they would make a triangle. I haven't made the program check if it's obtuse, scalene or acute yet but I will do that too. thank you for the links, I will definitely use those. I think you're right about he initialization blocks, need to alter those

Comment: At this point you're probably better off sticking everything besides the `while` loop into a method and looping over the method instead.

Comment: And for triangle identification I was more thinking that you need to either test all combinations of sides such that each side could be the longest, or you can sort the sides and compare the shorter two sides against the longer one.